# I am looking for a VGA to HDMI adapter which also works in the BIOS

Tags: hdmi, vga

I have bought a [(active) BENFEI VGA to HDMI adapter](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07K14NR8P) for 13€ on Amazon.

It works well when I am in Windows.

But it doesn't work when I am in the BIOS. It seems to be a common issue with such adapters.

Does anyone know a VGA to HDMI (or DVI) adapter which also works in the BIOS?

Comment: I'm in the same boat, bought a StarTech VGA to HDMI adapter, it doesn't work in BIOS, otherwise seems fine. Have you found one in the meantime?